# regular expression for "measure units"

Tags: regex

I need a regex that support custom measure units. For example:

```
1G Valid
GB Valid
1  Invalid
M2 Valid
mt valid
22 Invalid
```

Can support numbers with another words. But not only numbers. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Will the valid strings always be "two" characters?

Comment: Do not use tags when the question clearly contains nothing about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?!\d+$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/5

This will not allow a string containing only numbers.

You can use

```
^(?!\d+$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,2}$
```

If you want to allow only upto 2 digits

Comment: StackOverflow is not a "write a regex for me" service.

Answer (score 0):

How about the regex

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$
```

Example : http://regex101.com/r/nX3wA6/1

- `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` postive look ahead assertion. Checks if the string contains atleast 1 character.